# readable stream on data event losing first/last character from chunk

Tags: node.js, stream, readable

I am using ssh2-sftp-client for nodeJS to connect to sftp server and get a file
But I've meet a problem, when are more chunks than one, the data is not received correctly, it loses one character between chunks: 
ex.: file on sftp has 'some string from sftp file' 
and if it is splitted in chunks, the received data will be like: 
first chunk : 'some string f' 
second chink: 'om sftp file' 
in this example 'r' is lost

```
const getFile = readable => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let file = '';
   readable.on('data', (chunk) => { file += chunk; }); 
  readable.on('end', () => resolve(file));
  readable.on('error', reject);
});

const readable = await sftp.get(fileName, false);
```

sftp.get() return NodeJS.ReadableStream

Does someone meet same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I found the problem, in module sftp-stream, for readable stream highWaterMark is seted to 64*1024, and the bug is that if a chunk has 64*1024 bites then one bite is lost. And I just setted watermark to 64*1024-1 .

Comment: I am facing the same issue. changing watermark doesn't solve the problem for sftp.

Answer (score 0):

Is it more advisable to store chunks as a array and then concat them into a buffer and get the string value on end:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const getFile = readable => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const file = [];
  readable.on('data', chunk => file.push(Buffer.from(chunk, 'base64')));
  readable.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(file).toString()));
  readable.on('error', reject);
});


const readable = fs.createReadStream('package.json');

getFile(readable).then(file => console.log('file', file));
```

Runned it locally and getting the content of my file as expected.

Comment: I am getting in this error 
TypeError: "list" argument must be an Array of Buffer or Uint8Array instances

Comment: Problem is not because of syntax

Comment: Which version of node are you running, cause it should work I tested it locally on 8.6.0

Comment: I am using node: '8.5.0'

Comment: It don't throw error, but I get all file with :
ӭ<�Mv�]v��} �0�X��"{^�v���ڔ�^��b�{z��q�╗╔�ߞ;ԃt�O6�]��]���@U z�ڶ*'jS�z�����I��p═�~x�Rځ鞞�═�^; �5�]�׽��o}��H╗�

Comment: It is because of encoding unmatch between readable and writeable streams

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't solve the problem with lost character

Comment: This requires loading the whole contents into memory making streams pointless.